# Locate Registry Key and delete value

Tags: windows, powershell, registrykey, sid

I am trying to delete a binary value within my registry with this code the code prompts an error stating the value at DefaultConnectionSettings does exist but it's able to find the SID path, but not the exact DefaultConnectionSettings Value. I'm running this script on a test machine that has the DefaultConnectionSettings.
[RegEdit.exe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqEpD.png)

Any input would be helpful Thanks,

```
if (!(Test-Path 'HKU:\')) {
  New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS
}

($path = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKU:\*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) | 
  ForEach-Object { Remove-ItemProperty -Path $path -name "DefaultConnectionSettings" -force }
```

Comment: I've reduced the code to the one that tries to delete the registry values. Note that if yo do `$path = ... | ...`, `$path` receives the output from the _entire_ pipeline. To only save the _first_ command's output, you must use `($path = ...) | ...`

Answer (score 1):

The registry *value* you're trying to delete is a value of the `registry::HKEY_USERS\*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections` registry *keys* themselves.

- Note that you can target the  `HKEY_USERS` hive simply by prepending the *provider prefix* `registry::` to the native registry path - no need to map a new drive with `New-PSDrive` first.

By contrast, [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) looks for *subkeys* of the targeted keys.

- Note that registry *values* are considered *properties* of registry keys, not *child items* (the way that files are in the file-system).

---

Thus, the immediate fix is to switch from `Get-ChildItem` to [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), which returns objects representing the target keys *themselves*.

However, you can do it all with a single [`Remove-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-itemproperty) call (as with your own attempt, running from an *elevated* session is assumed):

```
$path = 'registry::HKEY_USERS\*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'
Remove-ItemProperty -WhatIf -Force -Path $path -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: Hey I made some Changes to the code. I was able to remove both DefaultConnectionsSettings & Saved LegacySettings in the Reg path by adding an extra line I just have a question, When I run the first part of the script it'll say  registry::HKEY_USERS\*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet  is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. I'm not sure how to address this issue the code still executes the next 4 lines and is able to delete both values

Comment: @HieuLe, this answer tries to address your question as asked, and as such it is hopefully useful to future readers as well. If you have a _follow-up_ question, please create a _new_ question post. But it sounds like you're accidentally submitting `registry::HKEY_USERS*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet` _as a command_.